# How to log requests to Google play services

Tags: debug

Sometimes my battery usage gives me a very high percentage  (e.g. 45%) for Google Play Services.  Is there a way to log the name of the app that may be causing this problem.  Please note that I am not looking for a way to clear the play services heavy usage - I just want to know which app may be causing the problem.

Android version: 9

Google Play services version: 20.39.15

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked `adb logcat`? As Play Services are an own process all apps have to use inter-process communication for sending/receiving something via PS. Such calls may be visible as Intent call in logcat.

Comment: Will using adb logcat require the phone to be always connected to the computer? If I use system tracing in developer options can I build a large trace file over a couple of hours?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have an Android 10 device, hence I can not answer your question about system tracing as it is a new feature of Android 10.

Comment: Thank you. I have System Tracing in my developer options on an Android 9 device.           

The System Tracing app is an Android tool that saves device activity to a trace file. On a device running Android 10 (API level 29) or later, trace files are saved in Perfetto format . On a device running an earlier version of Android, trace files are saved in the Systrace format.